# Should regex be used in a parser for an interpreter or compiler?

Tags: regex, parsing

When parsing a grammar, should RegEx be used to match grammars that can be expressed as regular languages or should the current parser design be used exclusively?

For example, the EBNF grammar for [JSON](http://www.json.org/) can be expressed as:

```
object ::= '{' '}' | '{' members '}';
members ::= pair | pair ',' members;
pair ::= string ':' value;
array ::= '[' ']' | '[' elements ']';
elements ::= value | value ',' elements;
value ::= string | number | object | array | 'true' | 'false' | 'null';
```

So grammar would need to be matched using some type of lexical analyzer (such as a recursive descent parser or ad hoc parser), but the grammar for some of the values (such as the number) can be expressed as a regular language like this RegEx pattern for number:

```
-?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

Given this example, assuming one is creating a recursive descent JSON parser... should the number be matched via the recursive descent technique or should the number be matched via RegEx since it can be matched easily using RegEx?

Comment: I'd use a decent parser if you have nesting. The individual components can use regex to generalize characters (notably with classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad and opinionated question. Hence, to my knowledge, usually you will want a parser to be as fast as possible and to have the smallest footprint in memory as possible, especially if it needs to parse in real-time (on demand).

A RegEx will surely do the job, but it is like shooting a fly with a nuclear weapon !

This is why, many parsers are written in low-level language like C to take advantage of string pointers and avoid the overhead caused by high-level languages like Java with immutable fields, garbage collector,...

Meanwhile, this heavily depends on your use case and cannot be truly answered in a generic way. You should consider the tradeoff between the developer's convenience to use RegEx versus the performance of the parser.

One additionnal consideration is that usually you will want the parser to indicate where you have a syntax error, and which type of error it is. Using a RegEx, it will simply not match and you will have a hard time finding out why it stopped in order to display a proper error message. When using an old-school parser, you can quickly stop parsing as soon as you encounter a syntax error and you can know precisely what did not match and where.

In your specific case for JSON parsing and using RegEx only for numbers, I suppose you are probably using a high-level language already, so what many implementations do is to rely on the language's native parsing for numbers. So just pick the value (string, number,...) using the delimiters and let the programming language throw an exception for number parsing.